# Shopify shop integration into Laravel

Tags: laravel, shopify

I want to add a Shopify shop into my Laravel app.
It's using Shopify customer's username and password into my Laravel login api.

Can I redirect the customer into his Shopify web page with login?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, Shopify offers the multipass feature for this exact purpose. To do so you need to generate a Multipass token with customer information and redirect user to the generated URL with token. More information for Multipass implelmentation is in [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/multipass).

> The Multipass login feature is available to Shopify Plus merchants
>   only.